# Splitting Output Lists From A Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, key-value

I have a practice question which is as follows:
[image: Practice Question]

My code was as follows:

[image: My Code]

My Output was as follows:

[image: Output]

How can I achieve the same formatting as it asks for in the question with each user on a new line out of its list format. I was able to iterate over val in the second code block but this created a new 'Python Coder(s)' line with Tim and Anne separated.

Comment: Post ur code as text instead of posting it as an image.

Comment: Just iterate over the list `val` and print the values

Comment: @Sushil Sorry I'm newish to the forums I'll make sure I do next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your last `for` loop with this `for` loop:

```
for key,val in programme.items():
    val_to_print = '\n '.join(val)
    print(f"{key} Coder(s) \n {val_to_print}")
```

Output:

```
Python Coder(s) 
 Anne
 Tim
Java Coder(s) 
 Sue
```